# mysqli recebendo boolean

Tags: php, mysql

meu site não está fazendo buscas ! Não consegui descobrir como se faz consultas pela caixa de pesquisa, tento acessar os carros do banco de dados e ele me traz o seguinte erro:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/u374984363/public_html/newcars/functions.php on line 61
```

meus códigos:

```
functions.php :

function buscarCarros($conexao, $nome){
    $carro = array();
    $conexao = mysqli_connect('mysql.hostinger.com.br','u374984363_ozzy','******', 'u374984363_ncars');
    $query = "select * from carros where nome = {$carro}";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
    while ($carros = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
        array_push($carro, $carros);
    }
    return $carro;
}

result_pesquisa.php :

<?php
include('menu.php');
include('conecta.php');
include('functions.php');

$carro = buscarCarros($conexao, $nome);
    foreach ($carro as $carros) :
        $carros['nome'];
?>


menu.php :

        <nav class="twelve columns">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="comprar.php">Comprar</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Vender</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form id="searchbox" action="result_pesquisa.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" class="search-top remove-bottom" name="pesquisas" placeholder="Qual carro você procura?">
            <!-- <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('searchbox').submit();"> -->
            <a href="result_pesquisa.php"><span class="icon-top icon-search"></span></a>
        </form>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Coloque `var_dump($conexao->error);` embaixo do `mysqli_query` pra ver qual foi o erro.

Comment: Troque a senha do seu banco de dados.

Comment: Trocada ! Desculpem pelo vacilo... quanto ao erro, fiz o indicado e recebi isso:
string(40) "Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'" 
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/u374984363/public_html/newcars/functions.php on line 62

Comment: Troque onde diz `{$carro}` por `'{$nome}'` na sua query e veja o que acontece.

Comment: Obtive isso: string(148) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1" 
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/u374984363/public_html/newcars/functions.php on line 62.. parece que esse codigo nao quer rodar :/

Comment: Colocou as aspas simples também, do jeito que está no comentário?

Comment: Agora sim e ele me trouxe isso: string(0) ""... o que houve ? ele não encontrou o que pesquisei ? olhando no banco de dados, o nome estava certissimo !

Comment: Vou colocar na resposta, já já você vai ver.

Comment: Ok ! obrigado, estarei aguardando !

Answer (score 1):

Você está passando a `array $carros` para o campo nome da tabela do banco de dados, imagino que você quis passar a variável `$nome` ao invés.

functions.php
Use prepared statements para evitar ataque de sql injections. Dê uma lida na discussão sobre os dois assuntos, em uma [pergunta daqui do S.O. PT.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php/3867#3867)

```
function buscarCarros($pConexao, $nome){
    $carro = array();
    //$conexao = mysqli_connect('mysql.hostinger.com.br','u374984363_ozzy','******', 'u374984363_ncars');
    // a variável $conexao deve vir do 'conecta.php', não precisamos conectar de novo
    $query = "SELECT nome FROM carros WHERE nome = ?";

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($pConexao, $query)) {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $nome);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $nomeResultado);

        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
            $carro[]['nome'] = $nomeResultado;
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    return $carro;
}
```

result_pesquisa.php

```
include_once('menu.php');
include_once('conecta.php');
include_once('functions.php');
//use include_once ao invés de include quando puder, para evitar de algum dia incluir 
//sem querer 2 vezes o mesmo arquivo, que pode gerar fatal errors e interromper   
//a execução dos scripts caso você esteja declarando alguma função nesses arquivos  

//pegamos o conteúdo que foi pesquisado
$nome = $_REQUEST['pesquisas'];

$carro = buscarCarros($conexao, $nome);
foreach ($carro as $carros) {
    echo $carros['nome'];
}
```

No menu.php faltou colocar o atributo method do `<form>` e um botão de submit, ao invés de um link que apenas leve a página para outra:

```
<nav class="twelve columns">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="comprar.php">Comprar</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Vender</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a href="">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form id="searchbox" action="result_pesquisa.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" class="search-top remove-bottom" name="pesquisas" placeholder="Qual carro você procura?">
            <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" />
        </form>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Não sei o motivo, mas o fundo do meu site ficou completamente preto, e alguns icones mudaram... a pesquisa também não retornou resultados...